# Win 8.1: Defrag Optimize Issue: Do you want to restore default optimization settings?

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystems, file-permissions, defragment, optimize

> **Optimize Drives**
>   *Do you want to restore default optimization settings?*
>
> Storage optimization is currently using customized settings created by
>   another program. Before you can modify the schedule, you must remove
>   the customized settings.
>
> [Remove customized settings] [Keep customized settings]

I've already run chkdsk without any errors as that was suggested as a fix online, so please do not suggest the same as I'm still getting this Message.

[image]

- Choosing Option 2: [Keep customized settings] > No output
- Choosing Option 1: [Remove customized settings] > Error, despite being Admin on my machine forever and consistently running things via "Run As Administrator" from context menu.

[image]

Update: Enabled local Administrator account [this way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/), logged in and still same message
`net user administrator /active:yes`
[image]
[image]

---

I have a 2 part question:

- How do I figure out & trace what caused this to come up? Which program or activity?

  - Before you say I may be using another Defrag app, I am not.
- How do I fix it / get past this issue? and maybe prevent it in the future?